# Replace character with tags (ex. *hi* to <p>hi</p>)

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace each set of wildcard symbols (`**`) with tags (`<p></p>`).

**For example, if I have:**

```
var stuff = array(
    "The color *blue*!!!!",
    "The color *red*!!!!",
    "The colors *red* and *blue*!!!!"
);
```

**I want to output:**

```
var stuff = array(
    "The color <p>blue</p>!!!!",
    "The color <p>red</p>!!!!",
    "The colors <p>red</p> and <p>blue</p>!!!!"
);
```

What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Can you post your code so far? What have you tried? Also, what's `array`?

Comment: Can we assume `array === Array.of` ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just run a simple loop:

```
for(var i=0; i < stuff.length; i++) {
   stuff[i] = stuff[i].replace(/[*]([^*]+)[*]/g, '<p>$1</p>');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var stuff = [
    "The color *blue*!!!!",
    "The color *red*!!!!",
    "The colors *red* and *blue*!!!!"
];


 var res  = stuff.map(function(o){
     return o.replace(/\*(.*?)\*/g,'<p>$1</p>');
 });
```

or just a loop

```
 for(var i=0, len = stuff.length; i<len; i++){
      stuff[i] = stuff[i].replace(/\*(.*?)\*/g,'<p>$1</p>');
  }
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rc3Y3/)**